# Oppositely Configured ConditionalOnProperty Beans Autowiring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have two separate beans configured with two custom conditional annotations that should be exact opposites of each other and never both autowired at the same time, yet both are being autowired. These annotations will be used on many classes, so I want to be able to reuse them throughout the application without duplicating the @ConditionalOnProperty configuration. Are my conditionals wrong, or is there a better way to accomplish this in code so I don't have to rely on @Conditional annotations for optionally autowiring beans?

Conditional annotations:

```
@Inherited
@Documented
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "my-prefix", value = "enable-this-thing", havingValue = "false", matchIfMissing = false)
public @interface ConditionalOnNotEnablingThisThing {
}

@Inherited
@Documented
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "my-prefix", value = "enable-this-thing", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true)
public @interface ConditionalOnEnablingThisThing {
}
```

Shared interface:

```
public interface SharedInterface {
    void doSomething();
}
```

Implementing classes:

```
@Component
@ConditionalOnEnablingThisThing 
class EnabledThingComponent implements SharedInterface {
    //code
}

@Component
@ConditionalOnNotEnablingThisThing
class NotEnabledThingComponent implements SharedInterface {
    //code
}
```

Class attempting to autowire that throws a multiple available bean exception:

```
@Component
public class MyConsumer {
    private final SharedInterface sharedInterface;

    public MyConsumer(SharedInterface sharedInterface) {
        this.sharedInterface = sharedInterface;
    }
    //code
}
```

Comment: sharing code with the good old, copy + paste seems to have solved the problem, but that's not really maintainable. A less WET solution would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I would like to first start off with saying this is not an ideal solution, but it worked for my specific usecase without too much heavy lifting.

The configuration class code:

```
@Configuration(MYCONFIG_NAME_CONSTANT)
public class MyConfig {
    private final GenericApplicationContext genericApplicationContext;

    public MyConfig(GenericApplicationContext genericApplicationContext) {
        this.genericApplicationContext = genericApplicationContext;
        configureConditionalBeans();
    }

    private void configureConditionalBeans() {
        if(//my conditional code) {
            genericApplicationContext.registerBean(
               //registration details for conditional bean
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Components that need to autowire in these conditional beans:

```
@Component
@DependsOn(MYCONFIG_NAME_CONSTANT) //optional will always be empty without this
public class MyConsumingComponent {
    private final Optional<[MyConditionalBean]> conditionalBeanOptional;

    public MyConsumingComponent(Optional<[MyConditionalBean]> conditionalBeanOptional) {
        this.conditionalBeanOptional = conditionalBeanOptional;
    }

    //more code here
}
```

The biggest caveat I found is that the beans autowired in this way are never found by @ConditionalOnBean annotations, even when the bean has the @DependsOn specified. This means that any additional conditional beans relying on these underlying beans being configured will need to be conditionally set up in the same way. This caused a large pain for me since the beans I was attempting to conditionally autowire were ones a Spring Boot library was looking for. This meant the Spring Boot dependent beans had to be manually configured as well. I would still be interested in a better solution than this, but this solved the immediate problem.

Comment: I may create another question with bounty asking why these beans are not visible since it's not related to this question... Would still like an answer as to why the ConditionalOnProperty annotations are not extensible. I won't mark this as the accepted answer since I do not find it ideal